# Where Photologue's Photo.get_previous_by_date_added() method defined?

Tags: python, django, photologue

Definition of Photologue model `Photo` doesn't contain method `get_previous_by_date_added`, as well as its parent model `ImageModel`.  `ImageModel` inherits from django `models.Model` base class which hasn't this method too.

But there is usage of this method in `Photo` model:

```
class Photo:
...
    def get_previous_in_gallery(self, gallery):
        try:
            return self.get_previous_by_date_added(galleries__exact=gallery,
                                                   is_public=True)
        except Photo.DoesNotExist:
            return None
...
```

Where its definition lives?  (link to Photologue [models.py](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/source/browse/trunk/photologue/models.py))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's added by the `contribute_to_class` method of `DateField`, as documented in the [model instance reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.get_previous_by_FOO) - see also the code of [`django.db.models.fields.__init__`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L640).

A lot of Django's model attributes are added by metaclasses or by external classes, so it doesn't always help to look directly at the models.Model source.